# How to Create a Lead assignment rule to a Salesperson based on the time limit of a Day

Tags: community

I have created a Lead assignment rule based on the Round Robin.

```
Where in if Round Robin is 1  send the lead to Sales 1
            Round Robin is 2 send the lead to Sales 2
            Round Robin is 3 send the lead to Sales 3
            Round Robin is 4 send the lead to Sales 4
            Round Robin is 5 send the lead to Sales 5
```

What i need is that there will be a **day** limit for each Sales person.

If the Lead Status is Open ( the Sales 1 hasn't been touched for a day) it goes to the Sales 2 and hence forth to Sales 5, then back to Sales 1.

Please check the code in the Lead assignment

```
     IF( AND (TEXT(Status) = 'Open', (NOW()-  CreatedDate >=1  )),
  AND(Round_Robin_ID__c = 2,   Owner:User.Email  ='dgeorgesebgmail.com')  ,
 OR(Round_Robin_ID__c = 1,  CONTAINS(Donor_Software_Used__c,'Compass'), 
CONTAINS(Donor_Software_Used__c,'Patriot'),
CONTAINS(Donor_Software_Used__c,'Agilion') ) )
```

Comment: And what have you tried ?  (1) time-based workflows ? (2) apex scheduled jobs ?

Comment: No Could you please let me know how to go through it

Comment: Where is the above code defined?  As a formula field on Lead?